# journald for systemd user services

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I'm running a lot of stuff using systemd's user-level service management. So far it's been great being able to take advantage of timers, conditional services, etc. but one thing that is sorely lacking is a persistent journal.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I can see service status via `systemctl --user status servicename.service`, but I can't see any logs via `journalctl`:

```
$ journalctl --user
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

Is there something that I need to do to get user-level journald support working?

Comment: Works fine here (Fedora 26). No idea how Ubuntu handles it.

Comment: Does Fedora run a user journal in its own process? Not sure how the journal works in user mode.

Answer (score 7):

Two things:

1. [Ubuntu systemd journal entries are not persistent by default](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1618188). Edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and set `Storage=persistent` to fix that part.
2. Unfortunately, [on Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd 239 `journalctl --user --unit=` does not mean the same thing as `journalctl --user-unit=`.](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1621) While the former may be more intuitive, the latter is likely what you want.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783134/systemd-user-journals-not-being-created/47930381#47930381) for Ubuntu 17.10 where setting Storage=persistent fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had not realized that the user I was trying to read logs from was a system user. Systemd directs logs of user services of system accounts to the system journal: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd/User#Reading_the_journal